# adding the progress bar to existing multi step form

Tags: javascript, html, css

please I have troubling with adding this progress bar to a multi step registration form, I would be very much glad if any one can help me in this.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Progress Bar</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="circle done">
            <span class="label">1</span>
            <span class="title">Personal</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bar done"></span>
        <div class="circle done">
            <span class="label">2</span>
            <span class="title">Address</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bar half"></span>
        <div class="circle active">
            <span class="label">3</span>
            <span class="title">Payment</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <div class="circle">
            <span class="label">4</span>
            <span class="title">Review</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <div class="circle">
            <span class="label">5</span>
            <span class="title">Finish</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
    $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');

    $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i-1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

    $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i-1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');

    $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i-1) + ')').addClass('active');

    $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i-2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

    i++;

    if (i==0) {
        $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
        $('.progress div.circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
        i = 1;
    }
}, 1000);
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}

/* Form Progress */
.progress {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40px; height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}

.progress .bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.progress .circle .label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.progress .circle .title {
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}

/* Done / Active */
.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
    background: #eee;
}

.progress .bar.active {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}

.progress .circle.done .label {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8bc435;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.progress .circle.done .title {
    color: #444;
}

.progress .circle.active .label {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #0c95be;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.progress .circle.active .title {
    color: #0c95be;
}
```

I just want to know how to link this progress bar to a multi step form. I tried several times, but did not work. This code is working very well but when I include multi step form with *fieldsets* it doesn't work.
Any help would be highly appreciated as I want to hand over this project to school.
Thank you..

Comment: correct your jquery link   `<script src=` instead of   `<script >src=`

Comment: and it should be the error only I think

Comment: If you want to use _fieldset_, then you have to change your code and add your _fieldset_ to it. This looks like a _ready to use_ code, copied from the internet. So please change your code accordingly and if you had any errors or problems with your new code, then edit your post and add your new code so we can help you.